# Eloquent relationships naming conventions

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have articles with categories

many articles each article belong to one category.

each category has many articles

article db name is "articles"

categoery db name is "article_categories"

```
class Article extends Model
{
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\ArticleCategory');
    }
}
class ArticleCategory extends Model
{
    public function articles()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Article');
    }
}
```

now my question is: how should I name the column in articles which will store the category id?

I tried naming it:

```
article_category_id
articleCategory_id
article_categories_id
articleCategories_id
```

all of them not working as if I do

```
$article->category
```

eloquent running this query:

```
select * from `article_categories` where `article_categories`.`id` is null limit 1
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have troubles with naming fields you can set your own keys:

```
public function category()
{
    $this->belongsTo('App\ArticleCategory', 'local_key', 'parent_key');
}
```

so you don't have to be aware of naming convenctions used by Eloquent.

Comment: Thanks I know this, just trying to understand what column name will make it work without telling its name

Answer (score 0):

article_category_id should be the correct one.

can you try replacing this code

```
class Article extends Model
{
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\ArticleCategory');
    }
}
```

with the code below if this would work
class Article extends Model

```
{
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\ArticleCategory', 'article_category_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: its working, but I want it to work without tell him the column name, what column it is looking for? as I am trying to understand the naming

Comment: try this one.  

class Article extends Model
{
    public function articleCategory()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\ArticleCategory');
    }
}. i think i had issues like this. i found it weird. what i did was changing the name of the method to the name of the model it is referring in camelcase form.

Comment: yap this one working.. so I really cant understand whats happeing. I though that the function name has no effect on the query

Comment: I know. it was not stated in the documentation. i think the best way to understand what it is doing is to inspect the code which i don't have time right now.